# Django Admin, missing id readonly field in StackedInline

Tags: python, django, django-admin

I have a StackedInline with a model that contains several fields (including an 'id' field):

```
class MyInline(admin.StackedInline):
   model= myModel
   fields = ('id', 'foo', 'bar')
```

This shows the 3 editable fields as expected, however, when setting those to `readonly`:

```
class MyInline(admin.StackedInline):
   model= myModel
   fields = ('id', 'foo', 'bar')
   readonly_fields= ('id','foo','bar')
```

The id field is missing, only the `foo` and `bar` appear (as non-editable).

This behaviour happened when using `StackedInline`, with `TabularInline` works fine

Why is Id missing and how can I add it as a readonly field?

Comment: Isn't an objects id always readonly?

Comment: Which version of Django are you using? With Django 1.11 I cannot put `id` into `fields` without also putting it in `readonly_fields` because it triggers a `FieldError id cannot be specified for * model form as it is a non-editable field` and if I put it, it works fine.

Comment: It's a custom charField set as a primarykey and it shows as an editable field in the admin.

I'm running django 1.11 and the problem is exactly the opposite, the field hides if I try to set it to readonly

Comment: If neither fields nor fieldsets options are present, Django will default to displaying each field that isn’t an AutoField and has editable=True, in a single fieldset, in the same order as the fields are defined in the model - django docs

Comment: @angrykoala. Did the below answer worked for you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First check that the `MyModel` model has a foreign key to the model that in which it will be declared as `inlines = [MyModel]`.

Something like that:

```
# models.py

class Album(models.Model):
    # various fields here

class AutoId(models.Model):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=10)
    album = models.ForeignKey(Album, blank=True, null=True)
    foo = models.CharField(max_length=12)


# admin.py

class AutoIdInline(admin.StackedInline):
    model = AutoId
    fields = ('id', 'foo', )
    readonly_fields = ('id', 'foo', )

@admin.register(Album)
class AlbumAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    inlines = [AutoIdInline]
```

With that set, using Django 1.11 and some dummy values for the `id` primary key, you should get this (*tested locally and works like a charm*):

[image: inline admin example]

Comment: I have TabularInline with readonly `id` sub when it's going to submit, `ID` is missing in `save_related` method